# Highcharts 'Cannot read property tooltipOptions of null'

Tags: javascript, highcharts

If have the following highchart:

```js
statisticsChart = new Highcharts.Chart({
  chart: {
    renderTo: 'advertisements-graphic-chart',
    type: 'line'
  },
  title: {
    text: ''
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      connectNulls: true,
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
      return "ceva";
    }
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: []
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: ''
    }
  },
  series: [{
    id: CHART_SERIES_IDS.ALL_PRINTS,
    name: "All prints",
    data: []
  }, {
    id: CHART_SERIES_IDS.ALL_VIEWS,
    name: "All views",
    data: []
  }, {
    id: CHART_SERIES_IDS.ALL_CLICKS,
    name: "All clicks",
    data: []
  }, {
    id: CHART_SERIES_IDS.MY_PRINTS,
    name: "My prints",
    data: []
  }, {
    id: CHART_SERIES_IDS.MY_VIEWS,
    name: "My views",
    data: []
  }, {
    id: CHART_SERIES_IDS.MY_CLICKS,
    name: "My clicks",
    data: []
  }, {
    id: CHART_SERIES_IDS.ADVERT_PRINTS,
    name: "Advert prints",
    data: []
  }, {
    id: CHART_SERIES_IDS.ADVERT_VIEWS,
    name: "Advert views",
    data: []
  }, {
    id: CHART_SERIES_IDS.ADVERT_CLICKS,
    name: "Advert clicks",
    data: []
  }, ]
});
```

at some point in time I do...

```js
statisticsChart.get(CHART_SERIES_IDS.ALL_PRINTS).setData(all_prints);
statisticsChart.get(CHART_SERIES_IDS.ALL_VIEWS).setData(all_views);
statisticsChart.get(CHART_SERIES_IDS.ALL_CLICKS).setData(all_clicks);
statisticsChart.get(CHART_SERIES_IDS.MY_PRINTS).setData(my_prints);
statisticsChart.get(CHART_SERIES_IDS.MY_VIEWS).setData(my_views);
statisticsChart.get(CHART_SERIES_IDS.MY_CLICKS).setData(my_clicks);
statisticsChart.get(CHART_SERIES_IDS.ADVERT_PRINTS).setData(advert_prints);
statisticsChart.get(CHART_SERIES_IDS.ADVERT_VIEWS).setData(advert_views);
statisticsChart.get(CHART_SERIES_IDS.ADVERT_CLICKS).setData(advert_clicks);

statisticsChart.redraw();
```

but after this point my console keeps shouting:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tooltipOptions' of null`

..printing it for tens of times each time I move my mouse inside the chart area.

I've tried debuggin the `tooltip.formatter` and `tooltip.pointFormatter` functions but it does not even get to those when that error shouts.

Comment: Could you create live demo with static data? Also, try 4.1.1 version.

Comment: I am also affected by this issue, using highstocks 2.1.3. It happens after calling reflow()

Comment: @AndrewGH [This was a bug and it has already been fixed at Highcharts v4.1.4.](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3863#ref-commit-5e0f859)

Comment: @falsarella make it an answer so I can approve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was probably a Highcharts' bug, see [***Tooltip exceptions when using addSeries on a chart with dataGrouping***](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3863) - reported one day after you aked the question.

Since it [has already been resolved](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3863#ref-commit-5e0f859) by [this commit](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/commit/5e0f85963c4f71d3fef7a571301bad62cced9562), just update your Highcharts to a more recent version like [v4.1.4](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/releases/tag/v4.1.4), or, better yet, [search for the latest](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tags).